# Synchronization: ImageDownloader thread

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I need to download (either from the internet or from my cache) a **lot** of images. Therefore, I decided to create a downloader thread which enqueues the images and notifies the caller when the image is downloaded.
The thread downloads any images in the queue, and waits for more images to be downloaded. In the `add` method, I wake the thread up to start downloading again:

```
public class ImageDownloader implements Runnable {

private boolean continueFetching;
private List<Image> images;

private static ImageDownloader instance = new ImageDownloader();

private ImageDownloader() {
    continueFetching = true;
    images = new ArrayList<Image>();

    new Thread(this).start();
}

public static ImageDownloader getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (continueFetching) {
            fetchAvailableImages();
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

private void fetchAvailableImages() {
    while (images.size() != 0) {
        Image image = images.get(0);

                    Bitmap bitmap = downloadImage(image);
                    image.onImageDownloadCompleteListener.onImageDownloadComplete(bitmap);

        images.remove(0);
    }
}

public void stop() {
    synchronized (this) {
        continueFetching = false;
        notify();
    }
}

public void add(Image image) {
    images.add(image);
            notify;
}

public interface OnImageDownloadCompleteListener {

    public void onImageDownloadComplete(Bitmap bitmap);
}
}
```

When I synchronize the `add` method, the UI thread hangs, because it needs to wait for the current images to be done downloading.
So I removed the synchronize block, but now I get `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: use this :-https://github.com/adig/RemoteImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better solution is to use this nice library that handles image downloading for you :)

user easy to use and also open source:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

why invent the wheel twice? :)

Answer (score 0):

i am use this source https://github.com/thest1/LazyList   works well, loads images asynchronously;)

I hope to helped you

Comment: he has a large source but I use "LazyList"

Answer (score 0):

1. notify modify to notifyAll..
2. when click UI/action ,create a new thread ... but,performance is slow,because once action create a new thread...